# When upgrading to support iPhone X, font display smaller on older devices

Tags: ios, user-interface, iphone-x

After I've added some launch images to support iPhone X, the label text diplay smaller. How can I fix this problem? Thank you!

- Before:

[image]

- After:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's neither bad nor unexpected. Without any launch image, the app runs as if this were a much smaller device, e.g. with a screen size of 320 x 480. That is narrower than the iPhone X so it is enlarged (zoomed) to the width of the device screen (so that we letterbox from the top and bottom, but not from the sides, as your first screenshot shows).

With the launch image, that letterboxing and enlargement goes away and you run natively with a screen size of 375 x 812. Now we are seeing more points of width on the same size screen, so the same point size font appears smaller, like a house seen from further away in a wider field of view.

You can easily confirm this by logging `UIScreen.main.bounds` with and without the launch image.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that but now when I run the app on older devices (ex: iPhone 6), the text become smaller too. About UI experience, it is unacceptable, right?
When upgrading to support iPhone X, to keep UI experience, will I have to increase all font-size? It is terrible because my current app have too much screens.

Comment: Same reason. Without a launch image, the iPhone 6 was displaying as a zoomed 5S. What you were seeing before was always incorrect. Now it’s right. Relax

Comment: Oh... I got it, from iPhone 5S to previous, the text keep the size. Understood, thank Matt.