# UIWindow rendering using LaunchScreen image vs LaunchScreen story board

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, launch-screen

After the migration request that Apple has been requesting since this summer. I have successfully implemented the use of LaunchScreen with storyboard.

But this is not without consequences.

It has an impact on the displayed UI. I was wondering if it was possible to continue using the LaunchScreen storyboard but still display the old way with a black bar above and below when displaying the UI after login. This is because I have a large number of screens to edit.

As example, if FinishedLaunching I use these line:

```
mWindow = new UIWindow(new CGRect(0, 10, 320.0f, 569.0f));
mWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible()..
```

Instead of

```
mWindow = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds)
```

I can see my UI rendered correctly. But it appears in the upper left corner instead of being resized to full screen.

Thanks.

Jp

Comment: This is on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

> the old way with a black bar above and below when displaying the UI after login

The black bar was your bug. Because you had no launch storyboard, the app was being displayed in a special letterboxed mode, occupying only part of the screen. (See for example [When upgrading to support iPhone X, font display smaller on older devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468204/when-upgrading-to-support-iphone-x-font-display-smaller-on-older-devices)) Now you have fixed the bug at last and your app is displaying correctly, occupying the entire screen.

Comment: It's not quite a bug. This is the old way of working before Apple decided to handle Launch Screens with multiple screen sizes with storyboards.

Now that Apple requires using the LaunchScreen as a storyboard. Do you know if is there a way that I don't need to convert all UI screens to be resizable? Thanks.

Comment: It _is_ quite a bug. You were supposed to have converted to fullscreen long ago. Accepting the letterboxed layout was just a lazy way out. You were doing this wrong and now you're caught; Apple now _requires_ that your view fill the screen. So you didn't do it earlier like you were supposed to, and you _must_ do it now. There is no "way that I don't need to."